# When using "Cover-Only" with pagination I can't get a table to show on the cover card

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

When creating a paginated card I was trying to get a table to show up as the cover card. It worked on the playground. On my glass though it just showed a blank screen. I'm not sure if this is a bug I should be reporting or if someone else has experienced this and knows a way to get the card to show as the cover card. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post an example of a JSON payload which reproduces this issue? Thanks!

Comment: I just reproduced this one. It looks like a bug. Can you please file it in the issue tracker? https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list